# Second-order differential equation solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What must be true of $f:R\rightarrow R$ for $f(x)f''(x)+(f'(x))^3-2(f'(x))^2=0$ to hold?

Answer (score 1):

The variable $x$ doesn't appear in the ODE. So, it it an ODE of the autonomous kind. The usual method to solve it is shown below  (where $f$ is replaced by $y$) :

[image]

Comment: Is that from a book or something?

Comment: @Aldon : About "autonomous ODE" ? This is from old memories from good old days when I was student ! I suppose that one can find it in any book about differential equations.

Comment: In case of autonomous ODE of n-th order, the change of variable $\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)$ is a method to reduce the order : If the initial ODE is of the first order, this is equivalent to a separable ODE. If the initial ODE is of second order, this reduces it to a first order ODE. If the initial ODE is on the n-th order, it becomes a (n-1)th order ODE. That all : it dosn't fully solve the ODE because the (n-1)th order ODE remains to be solved.

Comment: Great work as always. +1